# Отправка формы через enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<form action="login.php">
    <div class="af_row">
        <div class="descr">Номер телефона</div>
        <input type="phone">
    </div>

    <div class="af_row">
        <div class="descr">Контактный E-mail</div>
        <input type="email">
    </div>

    <div class="af_row">
        <div class="descr">Введите символы, изображенные<br>на картинке</div>
        <div class="af_captcha clearfix">
            <div class="af_captcha_block">
                <div class="af_captcha_img"><img src="images/captcha.png" alt=""></div>
                <a><span>Показать другую</span></a>
            </div>
            <input class="af_captcha_input" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="af_row clearfix">
        <div class="checkbox" data-name="register">
        <p>Я согласен с <a onClick="popup('register_terms');">условиями программы</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="af_row">
        <div class="button_container disabled">
            <div class="bttn button">Зарегистрироваться</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class='submit_hide'>
</form>
```

В подобных формах, после заполнения полей, последним пунктом идет чекбокс подтверждения "*условий соглашения*". Юзер ставит этот чекбокс и просто жмет enter.

Как в таком случае отправлять форму после нажатия enter?

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
    var sendform = $(this).closest('form');

    $(sendform).on("submit", function(e) {
        if(sendform.find('.button_container').hasClass('disabled')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(sendform).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? форма не отправляется?

Comment: Форма отправляется по enter, если курсор находится в input -e, в данном случае user при клике на "рисованный" чекбокс выходит из input и форма уже через enter не отправляется, событие submit не срабатывает.

Comment: А если в js после клика возвращать фокус на какой-нибудь input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить к чекбоксу аттрибут "required" . В HTML5 очень удобные встроенные возможности для форм.

```html
<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p><input type="checkbox" required name="terms">Я согласен с <a href="#" target=_blank>условиями программы</a></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

См. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/

Comment: У меня , как вы видите , чекбокс представлен ввиде div , править верстку и перестраивать под input type=checkbox я не могу т.к. верстка не моя.

Comment: Почитайте статью, ссылку на которую внизу поста прикрепил. Там внизу есть и про рисованые чекбоксы. Ну вообще код JS что вы привели правильный - только просто ещё в `$(sendform).on("submit" ...` надо добавить проверку на чекнутость вашего фейкового чекбокса. Какие он атрибуты имеет при чекнутости/анчекнутости - посмотрите DOM-инспектором, и анализируйте их в скрипте.